# ListView - change items from 1 to 2 lines

Tags: java, android, xml, android-activity, android-studio

How can I modify the code below so that each item has two lines instead of one? I want the code in the mSample section the same layout as I've posted so please do not inappropriately modify it unless it is necessary. Below is an image depicting what the list looks like with one line.

I know that the click event and list adapter codes needs to change, but I don't know what to.

I also have an xml called **list_item_entry.xml** that contains two text views (1 bigger than the other) in a linear layout but I'm not sure if I need to use that.

[image: list view]

```
package com.example.android.animationsdemo;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

/**
 * The launchpad activity for this sample project. This activity launches other activities that
 * demonstrate implementations of common animations.
 */
public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {
    /**
     * This class describes an individual sample (the sample title, and the activity class that
     * demonstrates this sample).
     */
    private class Sample {
        private CharSequence title;
        private Class<? extends Activity> activityClass;

        public Sample(int titleResId, Class<? extends Activity> activityClass) {
            this.activityClass = activityClass;
            this.title = getResources().getString(titleResId);
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return title.toString();
        }
    }

    /**
     * The collection of all samples in the app. This gets instantiated in {@link
     * #onCreate(android.os.Bundle)} because the {@link Sample} constructor needs access to {@link
     * android.content.res.Resources}.
     */
    private static Sample[] mSamples;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Instantiate the list of samples.
        mSamples = new Sample[]{
                new Sample(R.string.title_crossfade, CrossfadeActivity.class),
                new Sample(R.string.title_card_flip, CardFlipActivity.class),
                new Sample(R.string.title_screen_slide, ScreenSlideActivity.class),
                new Sample(R.string.title_zoom, ZoomActivity.class),
                new Sample(R.string.title_layout_changes, LayoutChangesActivity.class),
        };

        setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<Sample>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                android.R.id.text1,
                mSamples));
    }

    @Override
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView listView, View view, int position, long id) {
        // Launch the sample associated with this list position.
        startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, mSamples[position].activityClass));
    }

}
```

**list_item_entry.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:paddingRight="?android:attr/scrollbarSize"
    android:baselineAligned="false">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
        android:layout_marginRight="6dip"
        android:layout_marginTop="6dip"
        android:layout_marginBottom="6dip"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <TextView android:id="@+id/list_item_entry_title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:ellipsize="marquee"
            android:fadingEdge="horizontal"
            />

        <TextView android:id="@+id/list_item_entry_summary"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/list_item_entry_title"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@id/list_item_entry_title"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textColor="?android:attr/textColorSecondary"
            />

    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

**class errors**

[image]
[image]

```
package com.example.android.animationsdemo;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

/**
 * The launchpad activity for this sample project. This activity launches other activities that
 * demonstrate implementations of common animations.
 */
public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {
    /**
     * This class describes an individual sample (the sample title, and the activity class that
     * demonstrates this sample).
     */
    private class Sample {
        private CharSequence title;
        private CharSequence summary;
        private Class<? extends Activity> activityClass;

        public Sample(int titleResId, int summaryResId, Class<? extends Activity> activityClass) {
            this.activityClass = activityClass;
            this.title = getResources().getString(titleResId);
            this.summary = getResources().getString(summaryResId);

        }

        @Override
        public String toString() { return title.toString(); return summary.toString(); }
    }

    /**
     * The collection of all samples in the app. This gets instantiated in {@link
     * #onCreate(android.os.Bundle)} because the {@link Sample} constructor needs access to {@link
     * android.content.res.Resources}.
     */
    private static Sample[] mSamples;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Instantiate the list of samples.
        mSamples = new Sample[]{
                new Sample(R.string.title_crossfade, R.string.summary_crossfade, CrossfadeActivity.class),
                new Sample(R.string.title_card_flip, R.string.summary_card_flip, CardFlipActivity.class),
                new Sample(R.string.title_screen_slide, R.string.summary_screen_slide, ScreenSlideActivity.class),
                new Sample(R.string.title_zoom, R.string.summary_zoom, ZoomActivity.class),
                new Sample(R.string.title_layout_changes, R.string.summary_layout_changes, LayoutChangesActivity.class),
        };
    }

    @Override
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView listView, View view, int position, long id) {
        // Launch the sample associated with this list position.
        startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, mSamples[position].activityClass));
    }

    static class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

        static class ViewHolder {
            TextView title;
            TextView summary;
        }

        LayoutInflater inflater;
        Sample[] mSamples;

        public MyAdapter(Context contexts, Sample[] samples) {
            this.mSamples = samples;
            inflater = LayoutInflater.from(contexts);

        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return mSamples.length;
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return mSamples[position];
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return 0;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            ViewHolder viewHolder;
            if (convertView == null) {
                convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.entry, null);
                viewHolder = new ViewHolder();

                viewHolder.title = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.list_item_entry_title);
                viewHolder.summary = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.list_item_entry_summary);
                convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
            } else {
                viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            }
            viewHolder.title.setText(mSamples[position].title);
            viewHolder.summary.setText(mSamples[position].summary);
            return convertView;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe it will help you

```
public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {

   /*
     current code
   */

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     //
     //

       setListAdapter(new SampleAdapter(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
            mSamples));
    }

    @Override
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView listView, View view, int position, long id) {
        // Launch the sample associated with this list position.
        startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, mSamples[position].activityClass));
    }

    public static class SampleAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Sample>{

            SampleAdapter(Context context, int resource, Sample[] objects) {
                super(context, resource, objects);
            }

            @Override
            public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
                View rootView = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
                TextView firstLine = rootView.findViewById(R.id.list_item_entry_title);
                TextView secondLine = rootView.findViewById(R.id.list_item_entry_summary);
                firstLine.setText(getItem(position)./*Sample class field*/);
                secondLine.setText(getItem(position)./*Sample class field*/);
                return rootView;
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: Where does this class need to go?

Comment: it can be a subclass of your activity

Comment: Does it need to go in the same java file for my activity?

Comment: yes. or create new java file with name "SampleAdapter" and write this code.

Comment: What needs to go in **Sample class field**?

Comment: title and summary.I did not see the implementation of your Sample class

Comment: The edited java code above is what my code looks like for the activity

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67951/discussion-between-sorryformyenglish-and-user3293579).

Comment: and what should be in the second row?

Comment: Which line are you referring to?

Comment: list_item_entry_summary in layout xml file

Comment: I've replied in the chat section

Answer (score 0):

If you want to customise the rows with more than one `TextView` then you should implement your own Adapter. The xml you have posted is useless because you are using `android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1` and `android.R.id.text1`. To achieve what you want to do try this:

```
public class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    static class ViewHolder {
        TextView title;
        TextView summary;
    }

    LayoutInflater inflater;
    Sample[] mSamples;

    public MyAdapter(Context contexts, Sample[] samples) {
        this.mSamples = samples;
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(contexts);

    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mSamples.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return mSamples[position];
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder viewHolder;
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.entry, null);
            viewHolder = new ViewHolder();

            viewHolder.title = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.list_item_entry_title);
            viewHolder.summary = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.list_item_entry_summary);
            convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
        } else {
            viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
        viewHolder.title.setText(mSamples[position].title);
        viewHolder.summary.setText(mSamples[position].summary);
        return convertView;
    }
}
```

And you can use it like this:

```
list.setAdapter(new MyAdapter(this, samples));
```

Comment: I intend to use a large number of items 50+ and so I'd rather have a more efficient way to doing this.

Comment: Well you need to implement ViewHolder pattern in getView which is all over the internet.

Comment: It is using ArrayAdapter which has most likely implemented ViewHolder internally.

Comment: Is the code that 'SorryForMyEnglish' posted more efficient?

Comment: OK cool. 3 errors remain after implementing your code, which I don't know to resolve.